# What does the terminology "cross reference" mean exactly?

Tags: cross-referencing

When I am learning `LaTex` I can always meet with the word `cross-reference`, but I feel hard to understand it.

In most cases, It seems that `cross-reference` means simply `reference`. For example I can create a figure somewhere and cite it in another place. How does the `cross` mean exactly in this context?

Comment: Wikipedia says for cross-reference: "*An instance within a document which refers to related information elsewhere in the same document.*" Of course Wikipedia statements must be taken with a pinch of salt. Under "*reference*" I usually understand a reference to an *external* document.

Comment: this is more or less standard english term rather than latex-specific. If you talk about the references in a book you would (normally) mean the list of articles cited at the end `\thebibliography` in latex, if you talk about the cross references in a book you mean references within the book between sections (normally)

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments! I think David's answer is quite acceptable for me. Yes, It seems this is much about the english sense and `LaTex` has no duty on it. Also Thanks `campa` for your indication.

Comment: Btw, Do I need to close the questions? I am satisified with your answer.

Comment: I could answer or we could close as off topic or I think you can simply delete as it has no answers yet.

Comment: Hi David, Would you be happy to convert your comment as an answer?